# python - Import breaks, because library cannot import its own modules

Tags: python, import, module, mongokit

I'm trying to use mongokit in my Pyramid project, but when I import it, I get the following error.

```
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mongokit
  File "/home/.../mongokit/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from cursor import Cursor
ImportError: No module named 'cursor'
```

There is a `cursor.py` file with a `Cursor` class in it in the same folder as `__init__.py`.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), when you import a module, it is supposed to put its own directory at the beginning of the search path. However, when I print out `sys.path` from both `foo.py` and `__init__.py`, it is the same in both places.

I can't find anyone else having this problem.

**Edit:** I am using Python 3.3

Comment: Try to do `from .cursor import Cursor`

Answer (score 2):

mongokit is not compatible with python 3.

From their version notes:

**v0.9.0
now MongoKit requires PyMongo >= 2.5**

Answer (score 0):

The same error may occur if you use python 3.x and try to import some module for python 2.x.

Comment: I am using Python 3, so that may be the issue. Edited to add that information.